# Significance of ? in java template parameters

Tags: java, inheritance, collections

I noticed on a lot of occasion in production java code, the usage of

```
Collection< ? extends foo> var
```

My question is doesn't

```
Collection<foo> var
```

mean the same. What is the semantic difference of one versus the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Search for "[java] wildcard generics". (The `?` is part of a wildcard production and Java "templates" are [Generic (types)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a method

```
void foo(List<Parent> bar)
```

and we want to pass it `List<Child>`, unfortunately we can't. Generic containers aren't "covariant" if `Foo` is a subtype of `Bar` then `List<Foo>` is NOT a subtype of `List<Bar>`, they're invariant. To fix this, we use wildcards.

If we declare our method

```
void foo(List<? extends Parent> bar)
```

Now we can pass it a `List<Child>` or a `List<Parent>`. Wild cards with `extends` give us covariance.

Dually, if we want to pass a list of objects that `Child` is a subtype of, then we can do

```
void foo(List<? super Child>)
```

and pass it a `List<Parent>`. This is "contravariance", like covariance but flopped.

It's a slightly confusing topic, but the gist of variance is to allow collections to have the same subtypes and supertypes as their parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Collection<? extends Foo>` matches `Collection<SubClassOfFoo>`, while `Collection<Foo>` does not.

To put it simply, if `SubClass extends Foo`, then it is not true that `Collection<SubClass> extends Collection<Foo>`, so you need the use of the wildcard to signal that you allow for collections of subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<foo> var` means it contains only `foo` and its subclasses. `Collection< ? extends foo> var` mean it can contain only one specific subclass of `foo` and subclasses of that. It is quite different.